# Desktop App Converter failed with E_CREATING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED error (DirectoryNotFoundException)

Tags: .net, winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I'm trying to use [Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter), but it constantly fails with the **E_CREATING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED** error.

The inner exception that has sense is the *System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException*

```
Inner Exception[3]:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

From the log file, I've got the following.

Most probably the problem is in these two lines (please see below).

```
Setting up Conversion Environment

[2016-09-30T14:23:26] Copying contents of D:\MyApp to C:\DesktopAppConverter\ccba45a0-1360-478d-b9e2-66d32dbedc0d\shared\installer to be shared with isolated environment
[2016-09-30T14:23:26] Copying KnownFolderDump.exe and its dependencies to C:\DesktopAppConverter\ccba45a0-1360-478d-b9e2-66d32dbedc0d\shared\dac\bin
```

I investigated the *GUID*-named folder and found no "*SHARED*" folder inside. So, no contents of MyApp and no KnownFolderDump.exe. The "*dac*" folder exists, but under "*output*", not under "*shared*".

And the "*dac*" folder is empty. The exception *System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException* confirms my conclusion. The question is how to fix that?

The problem occurs on every conversion.

I cannot try to create the folders in advance because each time the converter generates and uses a new GUID.

I tried two different installers (InnoSetup and a plain self-extracting archive produced by 7zip). I also tried two different apps: WPF/.NET 4.0 and a plain Win32 app with no dependencies other than system libraries: *kernel32*, *user32*, *gdi32* and *msvcr90.dll*).

The 7zip self-extracting archive also depends on *ole32*, *shell32*, *oleaut32* and *msvcrt.dll* instead of *msvcr90.dll*).

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Have you checked [Prepare your desktop app for conversion to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root#prepare-your-desktop-app-for-conversion-to-uwp)? Not all desktop app can be converted to UWP apps.

Comment: I have checked these requirements, thank you for the link! However, all these requirements are addressed to the app not to the installer. But the converter uses the installer as a starting point. I have checked the dependencies of the installer, created by InnoSetup. It is written on Delphi and does not link directly to any C runtime. Now I'm going to try [to manually convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion) my app.

Comment: I have temporarily solved the problem by installing a fresh 14393 Enterprise build (from the Windows Insider program) to Hyper-V virtual machine. The converter works without any issues on that fresh environment.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be a problem with the Hyper-V setup on my machine. More specifically, the problem was with the creation of a virtual switch. (Have a look in the Administrative Events Log just after you get a failure). I suggest you look into that. I cycled the Hyper-v related services on my laptop and the converter started working.